# Extra spinner added on action bar android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have written a code to add two spinners on action bar using a custom view.It's coming OK,but an extra spinner is added to the left.Can't figure out why?Please help.

here is the img:

[image]

```
    mActionBar = getActionBar();
    mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
    mActionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    mActionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);            


    spinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.list, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);

                ((Spinner)mActionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.action_bar_spinner_collection_detail)).setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
                ((Spinner)mActionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.action_bar_spinner_collection_detail1)).setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
```

My xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="2">

<Spinner
android:id="@+id/action_bar_spinner_collection_detail"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
>
</Spinner>

<Spinner
 android:id="@+id/action_bar_spinner_collection_detail1"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_weight="1" >
</Spinner>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRtiQ.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of this. 
Your actionbar navigation mode is set to LIST_NAVIGATION 
`mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);` 
That is the spinner of navigation

And also did you requestWindowFeature - Custom Title ?

Comment: I changed the navigation mode to NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please Remove Your `android:weightSum = "2"` from Linear Layout of Your XML file

Comment: Hi

It did not make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST
    gives you a free spinner that is of no use to you.
(unless you have only one!, even then it has a hidden id).
NEVER use ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST or onNavigationItemSelected (witch only operates on the LAST entrty)
    use:
             final ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
             bar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
             bar.setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar_custom);
```

to define all your spinners.